# MYSQL cursor loop, runs one extra round, why?

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I'm looping through a cursor result set in a MYSQL stored procedure. I'm facing an issue which is that the loop always run thorough the last record twice. Here is my code,

```
BEGIN
DECLARE not_found_creadit INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur_credit CURSOR FOR 
SELECT customer_id, amount, status, user_type, employee, note FROM credit WHERE status = 'approved' AND customer_id = int_cust_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found_creadit = 1;
OPEN cur_credit;
  SET not_found_creadit = 0;
  credit_loop : LOOP 
      IF not_found_creadit THEN
        CLOSE cur_credit;
        LEAVE credit_loop;
      END IF;
      FETCH cur_credit INTO vc_customer, dec_amount, vc_status, vc_user_type, vc_emp, vc_note;
      SELECT vc_customer, dec_amount, vc_status, vc_user_type, vc_emp, vc_note;
      ......
      ......
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Means if I have 3 records, loop runs 4 times, if it is 10 records loop runs 11 times, etc. Any idea whats happening here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The handler, which sets `not_found_creadit = 1`, is fired when the `FETCH` returns no rows, but you are checking its value *before* executing `FETCH`, so the main body of your loop will execute one extra time when the `FETCH` fails, then the loop loop exits at the start of the *next* iteration.

Rearrange your code to check the value of your variable immediately *after* the `FETCH`:

```
credit_loop : LOOP 
    FETCH cur_credit INTO vc_customer, dec_amount, vc_status, vc_user_type, vc_emp, vc_note;
    IF not_found_creadit THEN
        CLOSE cur_credit;
        LEAVE credit_loop;
    END IF;
    SELECT vc_customer, dec_amount, vc_status, vc_user_type, vc_emp, vc_note;
    ......
    ......
END LOOP;
```

Also, consider correcting the spelling of your variable to `not_found_credit`

Answer (score -1):

YOU MUST CORRECT TYPE BECAUSE I WRITE DEFAULT (i dont know what You have in table credit). End If U create table TempTable use

```
TRUNCATE TempTable;
```

Please rewrite example

```
CREATE CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (`Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `employee` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`customer_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
```

ofcourse type is bad :)

```
 DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CursorX $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `CursorX`()
    BEGIN    
            DECLARE xCustomerId int(11);  
            DECLARE xStatus   int(11);
            DECLARE xUserType  varchar(255);
            DECLARE xEmployee  varchar(255);
            DECLARE xNote varchar(255);  
            DECLARE i int(11);
            DECLARE recordNotFound INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE cur_credit CURSOR FOR SELECT customer_id, amount, status, user_type, employee, note FROM credit WHERE status = 'approved' AND customer_id = int_cust_id;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET recordNotFound = 1;

            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable AS(SELECT * FROM credit);

            OPEN cur_credit;
            set not_found_creadit = 0;
            credit_loop: LOOP
            SET i = i +1;
                FETCH cur_credit INTO xCustomerId,xStatus,xUserType,xEmployee,xNote;
                IF not_found_creadit THEN
                    LEAVE credit_loop;
                 END IF;
            END LOOP credit_loop;
            CLOSE cur_credit;
    select * FROM TempTable;

    END $$
```