# Stored procedure in mysql doesnt insert fetched and iterated values into table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is what i tried. I couldnt get my values inserted into table. can anyone help me out ..

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `SampleDB`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Sample`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SampleDB`.`Sample`()
BEGIN
    #declare variable
    DECLARE tenantName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE tenantAddress VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT tenant_name,tenant_address FROM tenant;

    #open cursor
    OPEN cur1;
        #starts the loop
        the_loop: LOOP
            #get the values of each column into our variables
            FETCH cur1 INTO tenantName,tenantAddress;
            IF done THEN
            LEAVE the_loop;
            END IF;     
            #Insert it
            INSERT INTO tenant(tenant_name,tenant_address)
            VALUES (tenantName,tenantAddress);  
        END LOOP the_loop;

    CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you need to declare continue handler for your cursor
refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291573/mysql-cursor-loop-runs-one-extra-round-why

Answer (score 0):

Indeed lack [13.6.7.2. DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html):

```sql
...
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT tenant_name, tenant_address FROM tenant;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

#open cursor
...
```

But do you really need a cursor? With a statement like this, you can avoid the cursor:

```sql
INSERT INTO `tenant` (`tenant_name`, `tenant_address`)
SELECT `tenant_name`, `tenant_address` FROM `tenant`;
```